# fsck fails frequently(after each 3-4 boots)

Tags: kali-linux, fsck, superblock, e2fsck

I have triple boot System(Ubuntu,Kali,Win7) and I mostly use Kali 
linux(4.6.0-kali1-amd64). After each 3 or 4 successful boots i get this 
error ->

```
    fsck.ext4: Superblock checksum does not match superblock while trying 
    to access /dev/sda7
    /dev/sda7:
    Superblock cannot be read may be an invalid ext2 filesystem. 
    If yor device really formatted with ext fil system then
```

Superblock 
        may have been currupted try running e2fsck

```
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>

    fsck exited with status code 8
```

And after this as root cannot be mounted due to this error & enters into 
(initramfs) Console where i have to run fsck command.

**The Temporary Solution Worked for me is:**

I simply ran

```
    e2fsck -b "Magick Number" /dev/sda7 
     OR
    fsck /dev/sda7
```

and then rebooting kali worked perfectly but problem occurs again after some 
boots(as mentioned before). No such problem for Ubuntu.
So how do I fix it?
And Yes.. Does time affects on super block? Because there is incorrect time in my Kali but not in Ubuntu and Windows

NOTE:
e2fsck & fsck didn,t worked for me

**fdisk Output:**

$fdisk /dev/sda

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x851b9aac

Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2           206848  976762879 976556032 465.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       1175027710 1953521663 778493954 371.2G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda4        976762880 1175025663 198262784  94.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda5       1396195328 1911578623 515383296 245.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       1911580672 1953521663  41940992    20G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1175027712 1387147263 212119552 101.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       1387149312 1396193279   9043968   4.3G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Comment: Ideas: Check SMART data (smartctl) to see if your harddisk is failing. Do a memorytest to see if your RAM has problems. Check if you have some application that for some reason uses the partition directly, and can corrupt the superblock. `ext4` is mature enough that I don't think it's a bug causing the superblock corruption, but who knows ...

Comment: It could be that your partitions are overlapping. Run `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and look at its output.  Nothing should overlap (except for the extended partition, if any).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I've added the output. And it seems to be OK.