# Can't load Ubuntu: Superblock checksum does not match superblock while trying to open /dev/sda7

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, superblock, system-failure

I have a problem while loading into Ubuntu 17.04.
This happens for the 2nd time after I booted into Windows. For the 1st time I just reinstalled the Ubuntu. 
I am not good at this question, so I hope to get a full list of steps to diagnose and resolve this issue.
[image: Error stack]

As a workaround  `e2fsck -b <Magic number> <device>` has been used.

Here is the output of `fdisk -l` and it is seems fine to me:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F3EBBDD3-ABDB-4AD4-BBFB-9F97E38D2A2B

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    2050047    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     2050048    2582527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3     2582528    4630527    2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
/dev/sda4     4630528    4892671     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5     4892672 1029873663 1024980992 488.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  1029873664 1541873663  512000000 244.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1541873664 1737185279  195311616  93.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  1737185280 1741185023    3999744   1.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda9  1741185024 1953523711  212338688 101.3G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: Another person had this problem a few days ago. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367700/fsck-fails-frequentlyafter-each-3-4-boots Can you check if your partitions are overlapping?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks, I checked that. I didn't found any of overlapped partitions.
I've repaired the system by running `e2fsck <Magic Number> /dev/sda7` and `e2fsck <Magic Number> /dev/sda7`. But, I want to get the root cause of this behavior. Nothing extraordinary was done last time. And I'm using the same disk partitioning that I used before on Ubuntu 16.04, excpt that I've resized the partitions.

Comment: Today after booting into Windows I tried to load Ubuntu and got the same error. Never happened to me before. I've had dual-boot for years and it's worked perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849872/how-can-i-prevent-windows-10-from-corrupting-the-ext4-superblock-every-time)

64bit and metadata_csum features should be disabled

```
sudo tune2fs -O ^metadata_csum,^64bit /dev/sdXX
```

Comment: (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)
tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)

Please run `sudo resize2fs -s /dev/sdXX` to disable 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 5):

As I have tried the solution in the main answer for a superblock problem I simply got the same error.

My problem was that my Ubuntu system would not boot (under a multi-boot scenario) and couldn't be mounted from a different Linux system. In a live session gparted reported bad superblock.

I have followed this solution [here](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/), but the first step was enough for me.

In a live environment I did something like:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sda6
```

which reported the same problem but also offered to fix. I selected "y" for "yes" several times and then "a" (fix all I guess).

Everything worked after that, but only until the next Windows (7) boot. **The culprit in my case was the Windows program ext2fsd** - as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/857921/47206) - and removing that fixed this.

Comment: I found this useful...